# Argument is not sent from directive to controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have this `Controller` which has a method of sending messages  :

```
var app = angular.module('phoneApp', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope)
{
    $scope.leaveVoiceMail = function(number,message ,company)
    {
        alert("sending " + message + " to " + number + " via(" + company + ")");
    }
}]);
```

And a `Factory` service which has some data of communication providers :

```
app.factory('myFac', [function()
{
    return {
        networksArr: ["Verizon", "AT&T", "Sprint"]
    };
}])
```

And a `Phone` `directive` :

```
app.directive('phone', ['myFac', function(myFac)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:
        {
            number: '@',
            makeCall: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: 't.html',
        link: function(scope)
        {
            scope.networksArr = myFac.networksArr;
            scope.network = scope.networksArr[0];
        }
    };
}]);
```

Each Phone is a template (`t.html`) of :

```
<div>
  Number: {{number}} <br>
  Network:<select ng-model="network" ng-options="net for net in networksArr"></select>{{network}}
</div>
<input type="text" ng-model="value" placeholder="Enter phone">
<input   type="button" value="Call Home!" ng-click="makeCall({message: value, number: number , company:network})">
```

So here is the basic HTML :

```
<div ng-app="phoneApp">
    <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
        <phone number="123"   make-call="leaveVoiceMail(number,message,network)"></phone>
        <phone number="124"   make-call="leaveVoiceMail(number,message,network)"></phone>
        <phone number="125"   make-call="leaveVoiceMail(number,message,network)"></phone>
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks like :

[image]

I created an Isolated scope for the directive :

```
 scope:
       {
        number: '@',
        makeCall: '&'
       }
```

Where

- `number` value is taken as a string from the attibute
- `makeCall` value is taken from the html which actually sends message via:

  `ng-click="makeCall({message: value, number: number , company:network})"`

Where `makeCall` is *"linked"* to `leaveVoiceMail` method.

**Question**

It's all working except one thing — When I click the button :

[image]

Why do I get `undefined` in the alert box?

I **do** send values and I'm expecting to get :

> sending hello to 123 via(**AT&T**)

What am I doing wrong ?

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/iGygfJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `company` and `network` mismatched in your main HTML. In your `phone` element, use `company`. It needs to be company because that's what it's named in the controller method, and it's also what you're referring to within the directive.

```
<phone number="123"   make-call="leaveVoiceMail(number,message,company)"></phone>
<phone number="124"   make-call="leaveVoiceMail(number,message,company)"></phone>
<phone number="125"   make-call="leaveVoiceMail(number,message,company)"></phone>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/roqVte?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Probably just a typo on your part, but in the template you are passing the `company` local variable:

```
ng-click="makeCall({message: value, number: number , company:network})"
```

but use `network`:

```
make-call="leaveVoiceMail(number,message,network)"
```

Should be:

```
make-call="leaveVoiceMail(number,message,company)"
```